# How does RLIKE in Spark SQL treat the % char

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rlike

I have a table with a column that holds raw query strings. I want to find all the query string that match a certain patterns. some patterns starts with the `%` char.
I was wondering if the `RLIKE` in spark SQL behaves like the `LIKE` command in SQL or evaluates the `%` char and simply trys to match it with that char in the column values?
If by default it behaves like the regular SQL `LIKE` command (in regards to the `%` char) - is there any configuration i can change to change this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

No, `RLIKE` interprets the pattern as a regex, not in the classic SQL `LIKE` manner. It will treat % just like an ordinary char.

Note that there is also a `LIKE` function in Spark SQL, which behaves almost identically to classic SQL `LIKE`.

e.g.

`RLIKE`:

```
spark-sql> select 'ab%c' rlike 'a%';
false

spark-sql> select 'ab%c' rlike 'b%';
true
```

`LIKE`:

```
spark-sql> select 'ab%c' like 'a%';
true
```